# retornar string en una funcion

Tags: c

por ej, ingreso 20peso, y 1.80 altura, se obtiene imc<18.50. y quiero que me retorne el string asignado en sobre_peso en la función. que diga en consola, 'Estás sobre peso'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char calculoimc(float peso, float altura)
{
    char sobre_peso='Estas sobre peso';
    char estado_salud;
    float imc=0;
    imc = peso/(altura*altura);
    if(imc < 18.50){
        estado_salud=sobre_peso;

    return estado_salud;
            }

}
int main(){
    float p,a;
    printf("Introduzca su peso: ");
    scanf("%f",&p);
    printf("Introduzca su altura: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);

    printf("Su estado es: %s",calculoimc(p,a));
}
```

Comment: no creo que char permita una cadena de caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tipo de dato **char** es un caracter no un arreglo de caracteres o una cadena que es lo mismo, por tanto para representar esos datos debes usar un puntero a char o un string, este es el primer caso:

```
char* calculoimc(float peso, float altura)
{
    char* sobre_peso='Estas sobre peso';
    char* estado_salud = '';
    float imc=0;
    imc = peso/(altura*altura);
    if(imc < 18.50){
        estado_salud=sobre_peso;    
    }
    return estado_salud;
}
```

Comment: Solo por evitar errores tontos... los punteros deberían ser `const char*` para prevenir a nadie de modificar esas cadenas... esas cadenas son estáticas y cualquier intento por modificar las mismas puede resultar en una falla de la aplicación... esto incluye al tipo de retorno de la función

Comment: Bueno eso... y que las cadenas van con comillas dobles... no simples...

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias inconcistencias en el código. En C las cadenas son tratadas como **arrays** (vectores) y no se puede asignar un array a otra variable fácilmente con un "=". 
Tampoco se puede retornar un array con "return", este va a devolver la dirección de memoria del array (operaciones con punteros). Finalmente tienes un "Warning" al finalizar la ejecución porque a la función principal le pusiste `int(main)` por lo que obligatoriamente debe devolver un entero. En ese caso lo usual es poner un `return 0` al final.

Yo reescribiría el código de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float calculoimc(float peso, float altura)
{
    float imc=0.0;
    imc = peso/(altura*altura);
    return imc;
}

int main(){
    float p, a, imc;
    char bajo_peso[] = "Estas bajo de peso";
    char sobre_peso[] = "Estas sobre peso";
    char buen_peso[] = "Estas en el peso correcto";

    printf("Introduzca su peso (kg): ");
    scanf("%f",&p);
    printf("Introduzca su altura (m): ");
    scanf("%f",&a);

    imc = calculoimc(p,a);
    if(imc < 18.50) {
        printf("Su estado es: %s", bajo_peso);
    } else if(imc < 25.00) {
        printf("Su estado es: %s", buen_peso);
    } else {
        printf("Su estado es: %s", sobre_peso);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se te ha olvidado cambiar el tipo de retorno de la función `calculoimc`

Comment: Gracias, ya lo edité.